# Display error after empty inserted values to form NodeJs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a problem with display error after set empty values in fields(form). 
If I delete row with res.redirect('/') and after I try to register and later I will refresh the page, error will be displayed, but if I stay this row with redirect
I have no error, can someone tell me why?? And how to do that, after inserting empty values in a form, I will click on submit immediately will be displayed error.

```
router.post('/create', function (req, res, next) {
  var newUser = {
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  }

  req.checkBody('username', 'Login is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();

  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
     res.render('index', { 
      errors: errors 
    });
  } else {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, saltRounds, function (err, hash) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        newUser.password = hash;
        var user = new User(newUser);
        user.save()
          .then(function (User) {
            res.send(User);
          })
      }
    });

    req.flash('success_msg', 'You are registered and can now login');
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide. You can display some message **OR** redirect. Not both.

Eventually you can accomplish this on client side by using JavaScript or meta header

**Example generated HTML**:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.href = '/login';
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div>Logged out</div>
```

Comment: so, if I have /logout, so how can I redirect to page of login at the same time display on page statement you are logout?

Comment: Not at the same time. You can display message and after some time you can do redirection using for instance `setTimeout(function() {window.location.href='/login'}, 5000);`

Comment: Oh i know what u mean I have question to you, sec

Comment: I have do: { successRedirect: '/product/list', and its not redirect me to product/list but only in network is get product/list how to make redirect on page??

Comment: Ok I fixed that all, my fault is that i make request by ajax not by post form now all is overight code for example: router.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
  req.logOut();
  req.flash('success_msg', 'You are logged out');
  res.redirect('/');
})
All is working :) and u can make req.flash and redirect :P